# Loading saved context from AppDelegate to another ViewController

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data

I'm trying to make an array from my Viewcontroller equal to, the objects my core data has saved. I'm using core data and created an entity named Pokemon which has 3 attributes ***name***, ***id*** and ***generation***. In the app delegate, I use the following function to get Pokemon from this [API](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/). This is what I do to parse the data and save the context:

```
 typealias DownloadCompleted = () -> ()
 var pokemonId: Int16 = 0

func fetchPokemon(url: String, completed: @escaping DownloadCompleted) {
    let context = coreData.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let url = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, repsonse, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        }

        do {

            let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
            let jsonArray = jsonResult.value(forKey: "results") as! [[String: Any]]
            for pokemonData in jsonArray {
                self.pokemonId += 1

                if self.pokemonId > 721 {

                    self.coreData.saveContext()
                    return
                }

                guard let name = pokemonData["name"] as? String else {
                    return
                }

                let pokemon = Pokemon(context: context)
                pokemon.name = name
                pokemon.id = self.pokemonId
                print("Name: \(pokemon.name) Id:\(self.pokemonId)")

                if self.pokemonId <= 151 {
                    pokemon.generation = 1
                } else if self.pokemonId <= 251 {
                    pokemon.generation = 2
                }  else if self.pokemonId <= 386 {
                    pokemon.generation = 3
                } else if self.pokemonId <= 493 {
                    pokemon.generation = 4
                } else if self.pokemonId <= 649 {
                    pokemon.generation = 5
                } else if self.pokemonId <= 721 {
                    pokemon.generation = 6
                }

            }



            guard let nextURL = jsonResult.value(forKey: "next") as? String else {
                self.coreData.saveContext()
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.fetchPokemon(url: nextURL, completed: { 
                    self.coreData.saveContext()
                })
                completed()
            }

        } catch let err {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
        }



    }
    task.resume()

}
```

This is how I call it in the appDelegate. Really don't know what to do in the middle of the fetchPokemon or how to call it in another view controller. So I left it blank, not sure if this has something to do with the problem I'm having.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let context = self.coreData.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let pokemonListVC = self.window?.rootViewController as! PokemonListVC
    pokemonListVC.context = context
    fetchPokemon(url: pokemonAPI) {

    }
    return true
}
```

Im using this SQL-Light read-only app from the app store. I check the data and all 721 pokemon are saving. Now, I don't know how I would be able to make the array in my view controller equal to all 721 Pokemon saved. I added this code into my viewController.

```
class PokemonListVC: UIViewController {

  weak var context: NSManagedObjectContext! {
      didSet {
        return pokemon = Pokemon(context: context)
      }
  }
  var pokemon: Pokemon? = nil
  lazy var pokemons = [Pokemon]()
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      loadData()
  }

  func loadData() {
    pokemons = pokemon!.loadPokemon(generation: 1, context: context)
  }
}
```

I've created an extension of my Pokemon entity and added a function loadPokemon that filters the Pokemon by generation. Here is the code.

```
extension Pokemon {

func loadPokemon(generation: Int16 = 0, context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> [Pokemon] {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Pokemon> = Pokemon.fetchRequest()
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "generation = %@", generation)
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
        do {
            let pokemons = try context.fetch(request)
            print("My Pokemon count: \(pokemons.count)")
            return pokemons
        } catch let err {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
        }
    return []
}

}
```

When I call the loadData in my ViewController it crashes. The array count is 0 and so is the one in the hero extension. So I don't how to make my array equal the Pokemon saved from coreData.

Would really appreciate any help provided. :)

Here is my deleteRecords code, which is also in my appDelegate. This deletes all records when app launches. I call this method at the very beginning of didFinishLaunchingWithOption function before the fetchPokemons.

```
func deleteRecords() {
    let context = coreData.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let pokemonRequest: NSFetchRequest<Pokemon> = Pokemon.fetchRequest()

    var deleteRequest: NSBatchDeleteRequest
    var deleteResults: NSPersistentStoreResult

    do {
        deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: pokemonRequest as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>)
        deleteResults = try context.execute(deleteRequest)
    } catch let err {
        print(err.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that you have sure that all the pockemon records are stored correctly in your coredata you can simply fetch records from your codedata by providing fetch request. I have created demo for contact storing and I can get all the contact by this fetch request you can try this code in your ViewController where you want to fetch all the record.

```
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject> (entityName: "Pokemon")

    do {
        arrPockemon = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

    }catch let error as NSError {
        showAlert(string: error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

try to get all records first and if you get all then work for filtering extension and all. hope it will help you. you can learn from here https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-and-swift-core-data-stack--cms-25065

save flag on userDefault.

```
 //check for first time when app is installed first time(first time flag is not present so)
    let userDefault = UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation()
    if userDefault.keys.contains("isDataAvailable") {
        //key is availebe so check it
        if userDefault["isDataAvailable"] as! String == "1"{
            //no need to call server for data
        }else{
            //fetch data from server
            // once you get data from server make isDataAvailable flage as 1
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue("1", forKey: "isDataAvailable")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }
    }
    else{
        //flag is not avalable so call server for data
        // once you get data from server make isDataAvailable flage as 1
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue("1", forKey: "isDataAvailable")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
```

Comment: I don't have the core data stack in the app delegate. I moved it from the app delegate to a separate file that I created.

Comment: okay then you can try with this, let context = coreData.persistentContainer.viewContext and try to fetch record.

Comment: Okay it was working at first when I commented out my deleteRecords() method but when I uncommented it the array was 0.

Comment: please post what you have in deleteRecords() and where you are calling this.

Comment: Just added the deleteRecords fucntion

Comment: why are you deleting all these records ?

Comment: then you need to store one flag in userDefault and check that flag every time. e.g take isDataAvailable as a string flag and change it to "1" when you get first time data from server. now every time check that flag if flag is 1 then no need to call fetch data from server.

Comment: Otherwise what you have to do if you need to use delete function then first delete all the records then call server for data and then fetch records.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140218/discussion-between-luis-ramirez-and-prince).